# footer_links not displaying Magento 1.9.1

Tags: footer

Help, I am missing on the frontend homepage the footer: company with about us, etc. etc.
On the backend under: CMS/pages, the about us pages is enabled?
Can anyone provide help?

Answer (score 3):

You may have to use BACKEND option: CMS/STATIC BLOCKS/footer_links_company (identifier)
edit the content with your updated about us page link.
For better understanding images are attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dear KwodKewe, Thank you for youre help: This images are very clear. I found out that I am missing the static block: footer-Links_Company? How do I make such static block voor Company?

Comment: Just once again create static block identifier with the same "footer_links_company"

Comment: Please set the answer as "accepted" if your problem is solved: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers