# Magento 1.9 Footer Links

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, footer

I am trying to edit out the Quick Links and other Footer links so that I can install some widgets in that area that I created with Static Blocks. I cannot find where the links are located. I have tried all the pages that were default installations, same with Static blocks. I cannot find the links in the XML in the footer file.

I am a PHP developer, but brand new to Magento. It's driving me nuts that I cannot find these links and why my widget content aren't being added to the Footer section. Can someone please help? Every piece of Footer Links content I found on the Internet refers to Magento 1.7, which has a Footer Links page installed. Magento 1.9 doesn't have a page like that.

I loaded Magento 1.9 on my computer using XAMPP.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've answered a similar question before, here:

[Changing the footer in magento theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/changing-the-footer-in-magento-theme/22075#22075)

Just so this is a proper answer though, the footer for the 1.9 RWD theme is declared in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`, the blocks are named `footer_links` and `footer_links2`.

You can get rid of them entirely by creating a `local.xml` (best practice as opposed to just editing page.xml) file in the layout folder and putting this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links"/>
            <remove name="footer_links2"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Inside that reference node you can also add your own blocks or widgets.  Welcome to the world of Magento!

Answer (score 0):

Try the instruction in the given link [footer_links not displaying Magento 1.9.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31267/footer-links-not-displaying-magento-1-9-1/)
This may give you some hint to create and edit footer links.
If you need to create your own then you need to specify identifier in local.xml